# Why Can't I get That url link with cURL without integer value?

Tags: php, curl, web-development-server

I got the integer value that how much money in that page. But i want to get product name, url and price. How can i got it? How can i fix the problem?

```
 if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        $search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#", "", $search);
        $url = "https://ryanscomputers.com/catalogsearch/result/?q='.$search";

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        preg_match_all('/<span class="price">(.*?)<\/span>/', $result, $matches);
        $info = array_values(array_unique($matches[0]));
        for ($i=0; $i < count($info); $i++){
            echo $info[$i];
        }

        preg_match_all('!<h2 class="product-name"><a href="[^\s]*?"!', $result, $matches);
        $infourl = array_values(array_unique($matches[0]));
        for ($i=0; $i < count ($infourl); $i++) {
            echo $infourl[$i];
        }
        curl_close($curl);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read up on [how to parse XML/HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662#3577662), because [you are doing it very wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003). (do not parse html with regex)

that said, this can be parsed out rather easily with DOMDocument + DOMXPath, check

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");
$ch = curl_init('https://ryanscomputers.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=cat');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
foreach ($xp->query("//div[contains(@class,'item-inner')]") as $item) {
    //var_dump($domd->saveHTML($item));
    $name = $xp->query(".//h2[contains(@class,'product-name')]", $item)->item(0)->textContent;
    $name = trim($name);
    $price = $xp->query(".//div[contains(@class,'price-box')]", $item)->item(0)->textContent;
    $price = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$price));
    $url=$item->getElementsByTagName("a")->item(0)->getAttribute("href");
    print_r([
        'name' => $name,
        'price' => $price,
        'url' => $url,
    ]);
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Black Cat BC-01 Laptop Cooler
    [price] => Regular Price Tk 660 Special Price Tk 650
    [url] => https://ryanscomputers.com/black-cat-bc-01-laptop-cooler.html
)
Array
(
    [name] => Black Cat BC-02 Laptop Cooler
    [price] => Regular Price Tk 660 Special Price Tk 650
    [url] => https://ryanscomputers.com/black-cat-bc-02-laptop-cooler.html
)
Array
(
    [name] => Black Cat BC-06 Laptop Cooler
    [price] => Regular Price Tk 910 Special Price Tk 900
    [url] => https://ryanscomputers.com/black-cat-bc-06-laptop-cooler.html
)
Array
(
    [name] => Black Cat BC-07 Laptop Cooler
    [price] => Regular Price Tk 910 Special Price Tk 900
    [url] => https://ryanscomputers.com/black-cat-bc-07-laptop-cooler.html
)
Array
(
    [name] => Black Cat BC-05 Notebook Cooler
    [price] => Regular Price Tk 720 Special Price Tk 700
    [url] => https://ryanscomputers.com/black-cat-bc-05-notebook-cooler.html
)
Array
(
    [name] => Black Cat K-680 Mini USB Keyboard
    [price] => Regular Price Tk 420 Special Price Tk 400
    [url] => https://ryanscomputers.com/black-cat-k-680-mini-usb-keyboard.html
)
~~truncated
```